# Ruby method output limited when run with terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I am scratching my head on this problem, I am new to ruby and have been following along with Chris Pines book.  One exercise had us re-write the code for a "99 bottles of beer" program but this time using a method.  The problem is when I run the code, if the parameter is anything greater than 255 I only get "255 bottles of beer".  I have attached the code. This is the first method I’ve written so may not be the prettiest things.

```
def bottles num
if num < 0 # Making sure a positive is entered.
    return 'Please enter positive bottle count'
end
while num > 0 
    puts num.to_s + ' bottles of beer on the wall, ' + num.to_s + ' bottles of beer'
    num = num - 1 # Taking away a bottle.
    puts 'take one down, pass it around, ' + num.to_s + ' bottles of beer on the wall.'
end

if num == 0
    puts 'Ut-oh, out of beer...'
end
end

bottles 1000
```

So when this runs in terminal, the output would be like so:

255 bottles of beer on the wall, 255 bottles of beer
take one down, pass it around, 254 bottles of beer on the wall.
254 bottles of beer on the wall, 254 bottles of beer
take one down, pass it around, 253 bottles of beer on the wall.

Thanks!

Comment: Runs fine for me. Note you don't nee `if num == 0`; `num` will be zero.

Comment: As I said, your code runs fine, counting all the way down to one, then `'Ut-oh, out of beer...'`.  If it's not working for you, make sure you are running the same code that you posted (or cut and past the code above and run it).

Comment: I tried cutting and pasting, no luck. For some reason when I changed the num parameter to a different name 'beer' I was able to print starting at 549 and counting all the way down.

Comment: That may be an important clue (it working with `beer`, but not `num`).  Do you have any `require` statements?  What Ruby version are you using?

Comment: No require statments, ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux].  What's strange to me is that it worked better with beer instead of num.  549 vs 255.  Was shooting for 1000.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps the scroll back buffer is to small in your terminal. Check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904796&s=fb6299bca7b1997a4e9ed79863609af6&p=11589026#post11589026) out.

Comment: tried this works the same way my code does.  Prints from 549 down to 0.

Comment: Perhaps the scroll back buffer is to small in your terminal. Check this out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904796&s=fb6299bca7b1997a4e9ed79863609af6&p=11589026#post11589026

Comment: That's it! worked once I increased the scroll buffer.  If you want to post as an answer I can accept it.